# How to invert the grid in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, svg

Hi i have drawn a grid with 5 x-lines and 5 y-lines. The problem is that in svg the y direction falling downwards so my grid y lines falling downwards, to get grid in upward direction i given -ve values for y like (0,-50,-100,-150,-200) after this i got what i am expected but i no need to -ve values for y. How can i get the y lines in upward direction
i am getting first struggling to do second?

[image]

```
var Y = [0,50,100,150,200];
var X = [0,50,100,150,200];
var min_x = 0;
var max_x = 200;
var min_y = 0;
var max_y = 200;


var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);

var yLinesGroup = svgContainer.append("g")
    .attr("id", "ylines");

var ylines = yLinesGroup.selectAll("line")
    .data(Y)
    .enter()
    .append("line");

var ylinesAttributes = ylines
    .attr("x1", min_x - 30)
    .attr("y1", function (d) { return (d); })
    .attr("x2", max_x + 30)
    .attr("y2", function (d) { return (d); })
    .style("stroke", "red")

ylines
    .on("mouseover", function () {
        var pos = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(this).style("stroke", "black")
            .append("svg:title")
            .text("X:" + pos[0] + ";Y:" + pos[1]);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
        d3.select(this).style("stroke", "gray").text("");
    });

var xLinesGroup = svgContainer.append("g").attr("id", "xlines");

var xlines = xLinesGroup.selectAll("line")
    .data(X)
    .enter()
    .append("line");

var xlinesAttributes = xlines
    .attr("x1", function (d) { return d; })
    .attr("y1", min_y - 30)
    .attr("x2", function (d) { return d; })
    .attr("y2", max_y + 30)
    .style("stroke", "green")

xlines
    .on("mouseover", function () {
        var pos = d3.mouse(this);
        d3.select(this).style("stroke", "black")
            .append("svg:title")
            .text("X:" + pos[0] + ";Y:" + pos[1]);
        })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
        d3.select(this).style("stroke", "gray").text("");
    });
```

Comment: Where you want a set of input data to map a range of output values, then scales are often the best solution.
For example, using a d3.scaleLinear.domain([50,400]).range([400,50]) may be worthwhile (see more here https://github.com/d3/d3-scale)

Answer (score 1):

Try with this which may help you out

```
 var width = 700,height = 400,padding = 100;

    var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);


    var yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 500]).range([height - padding, padding]);  



            var xScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 500]).range([padding,height - padding]);  



            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("left").scale(yScale);


            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().orient("bottom").scale(xScale);


            vis.append("g").attr("transform", "translate("+padding+",0)").call(yAxis);


            vis.append("g")
                .attr("class", "xaxis")   
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - padding) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);


           vis.selectAll(".xaxis text") 
              .attr("transform", function(d) {
                  return "translate(" + this.getBBox().height*-2 + "," + this.getBBox().height + ")rotate(-45)";
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me exactly what you want to achieve. If you want to change the mapping of Y values so that more positive data values correspond to a position "higher" on the page, then, as others have suggested, scales are the right approach.

If you simply want to change the text that's shown on `mouseover` events, you can do that in the code directly, e.g.

```
.text("X:" + pos[0] + ";Y:" + (y_max - pos[1]));
```

Comment: that mouse over event for showing x and y coordinates like (0,0) (0,5)....

Comment: scales is the right approach but i didn't get how to do, is it possible to give me an answer for second grid which i am showing in image